# Settings for User agent switcher in Chrome developer tools - Where has it gone?

Tags: google-chrome, emulator, google-chrome-devtools, user-agent

I'm trying to find the Devices settings for Emulation in Chrome developer tools too add some user agents. I can open the emulation tool, but I cannot find the setting to add other useragents, as outlined here:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

> Custom Devices
>   Device Mode offers a wide array of devices for emulation. You can add a custom device if you find an edge-case or niche device that isn't covered. To add a custom device do the following:
>
> Go to the DevTools Settings. Activate the Devices tab. Click on the
>   "Add custom device" button at the bottom of the panel. Fill in the
>   form that appears at the top of the list. Press "Add Device" Enable
>   Device Mode and find your custom device in the device menu. Adding a
>   custom device

[image]

I do not have a 'Devices' tab in my Settings. I'm using Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for that same missing option too. After much fiddling, I realize that the user agent string can be set under Menu:

- More tools > Developer tools
- Toggle device mode (the 2nd tab on the left; no, don't go to Settings)

Screenshot:

[image: user agent string]